# Difference between aem-api and uber-jar?

Tags: maven, aem

Which one of the below dependencies should be used for building aem6.1 and aem6.2 projects using maven?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.adobe.aem</groupId>
    <artifactId>aem-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

OR

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.adobe.aem</groupId>
    <artifactId>uber-jar</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.0</version>
    <classifier>apis</classifier>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

The major difference is that the 6.2.0 version is finally an UNobfuscated API. Therefore, I would use the 6.2.0 version since it makes testing more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

The second one as the `<version>6.2.0</version>` is directly related with the AEM version.

You should also make sure it's consistent with your ServicePack versions when they'll be installed on your instance (once there is one)

Answer (score 0):

Recommend to use: 
uber-jar
6.2.0

For reference http://blog.justinedelson.com/2016/04/27/recompile-code-for-aem62.html